# CSS transition ease-in-out didn't messed up the images on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the transition for the portfolio section of my web, I need the effects on hover for portfolio thumbs and i have the following codes in CSS:

```
.proimg img {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; 
}

.proimg img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
  transition: all 0.55s ease-in-out;
}
```

That's the portfolio page http://goo.gl/Gaja7v
On hover, images didn't look good. Transition works but it messed up the thumbs, doesn't look good. I would like to make the transition to similar as this website http://goo.gl/0hb56Z

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to resize list images for that!

--

I recommend jQuery, fadeTo function

```
//you have to include jquery lib
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

//HTML : 
<img src="http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/wp-content/uploads/casad.jpg">

//Javascript :
<script>
$('img').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
</script>
```

you can get more information about fade to function 
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeto.asp

If you don't want to use fadeTo function.

```
//CSS 
.fadeeffect {
            -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
             transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

//Javascript 
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).css('opacity', 0.7);
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).css('opacity', 1);
            });
});

//HTML
<img class="fadeeffect" id="a" src="http://pjvarquitetura.com.br/wp-content/uploads/casad.jpg">
```

Comment: I did this, add the jquery and script too. Still no difference.

Comment: In my point of view, your webpage image size is too huge, you have to make thumbnail images for that. thanks

Comment: http://goo.gl/0hb56Z  // this web site list image sizes are 220 x 155, but  portfolio list sime image size is 1700 x 900 (over 700kb). that is why this web site image didn't look good,

Comment: Exactly, i got it. Images are too big so this effect looks terrible in bigger images and fine in portfolio item with small featured images.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to think of the transition **property** as an "action": eg, "When this :hover state begins, transition the given properties." But you really need to think of it as a *constant state*, which means "*when the following properties change, for any reason, transition them in this manner.*"

So you really want the `transition` property to be on your first CSS rule, so that it always applies. Otherwise, the transition is only when the mouse starts to hover, not when it leaves.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the transition property to your `img` as well:

```
.proimg img {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; 
  transition: all 0.55s ease-in-out; /* this line */
}

.proimg img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
  transition: all 0.55s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbPKVR

This is explained by Katana314's answer.

Comment: Added this line in img property, still the same issue.

Comment: Check if there is any other conflicting properties in your css.

Comment: It's caused up due to bigger images size, nothing else. Thanks